# How do I prevent Docker from listening on my public / all IPs in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v, docker

I'm using the latest version of Docker for Windows, on Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit. When I run the following docker-compose.yml, Docker listens on my public IP, 127.0.0.1, and my router assigned address.

Since I'm only using Docker for Windows for local development, I'd prefer it **not** listen on my public IP at all, ideally through a setting in Docker or Hyper-v itself, rather than through my firewall or router.

Is there a way to keep Docker itself (Not per-container) listening **only** on 127.0.0.1, or at least not on any public addresses?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
     image: tutum/apache-php
     build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-php
     environment:
       - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
     ports:
       - "80:80"
```

Comment: you can take a look here: https://forums.docker.com/t/can-i-change-the-default-ip-from-0-0-0-0-when-binding/30358/5

Comment: Doesn't work, it still listens on all IPs